# What ribbon controls are used for creating Excel 2016 Formulas items (AutoSum, Recently Used, Logical etc)

Tags: excel, visual-studio, vsto, ribbon-control

What ribbon controls are used for creating the Formulas ribbon items in Excel 2016?

I would like to create an Office VSTO Add-in with similar ribbon with similar ribbon items, large icons, menu like drop down and with scroll sidebar if necessary. I'm using VS 2017 and Ribbon designer.

Comment: Do you have the list of control IDs? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks. Solved the problem!